# Passenger, Apache and avoiding page caching

Tags: apache, caching, passenger

I'm hosting a rack application with passenger and apache. The application is setup to cache the content of each request to the public directory after each request. This allows apache to serve the content directly as a static page for future requests.

I would like to tell Apache, presumably through some rewrite rules that any requests with query parameters should not be cached, but instead passed down to the rack application. With a mongrel setup I would just redirect it to the balancer if it meets my rewrite conditions. How do you do the same with passenger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a bug and should be handled by passenger:

http://code.google.com/p/phusion-passenger/issues/detail?id=480